# Circular dependencies with custom entity-viewmodel mapper

Tags: c#, mapping

Let's say I have `Patient` and `Cycle` domain entities which I'm loading via EF:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Cycle> Cycles { get; set; }

    public Patient()
    {
        Cycles = new List<Cycle>();
    }
}

public class Cycle
{
    public int CycleId { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, `Patient` has a navigation property for a collection of `Cycles` and `Cycles` has a navigation property reference back to `Patient`.

Previously, I've used AutoMapper, but would like to have complete control over my domain entity-viewmodel mappings so I'm creating custom mappers.  Here is the one for `Patient`:

```
public class PatientMapper : IPatientMapper
{
    private readonly ICycleMapper cycleMapper;

    public PatientMapper(ICycleMapper cycleMapper)
    {
        this.cycleMapper= cycleMapper;
    }

    public PatientViewModel GetViewModel(Patient patient)
    {
        if (patient == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var viewModel = new PatientViewModel();
        viewModel.PatientId = patient.PatientId;
        viewModel.Name = patient.Name;
        viewModel.Cycles = patient.Cycles.Select(x => cycleMapper.GetViewModel(x)).ToList();

        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I need to inject a `CycleMapper`.  In `CycleMapper`, I'd need to inject an instance of `PatientMapper` to map the `Patient` navigation property.  This causes a cyclic DI issue.

I've resolved this in the past by creating a "basic" version of each entity.  For instance, `BasicCycle` would not have a `Patient` navigation property.  This works, but requires a lot more entities, mappers, etc.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Instead of injecting instance - inject a factory (`Func<ICycleMapper>` or a custom factory).

Comment: @Evk Thanks for your reply.  I'm not fully grasping.  Can you post a kopy.io?

Comment: Do you need "Cycles" outside of a patient bound to it? If not then why not change your GetViewModel definition in CycleMapper with a new one like cycleMapper.GetViewModel(patient). From what I understand your cycle only needs a patient instance to fill it's Patient navigation property.

Comment: @Alaminut Depending on the situation, I may be querying a Cycle in which case I may want to know the Patient, or I may be querying a Patient wanting to know its Cycles.

Comment: You said that the problem is circular DI. To avoid that, don't inject instance of ICycleMapper, but instead inject a way to create new instance when needed (factory). Some containers allow to do that without additional efforts, for other containers you will need to create factory yourself. Which container you use?

Comment: @Evk Autofac currently

Comment: You can solve that with autofac by just replacing `public PatientMapper(ICycleMapper cycleMapper)` with `public PatientMapper(Func<ICycleMapper> cycleMapper)` (and same for other mapper). But still you will have to solve infinite loop detection after that.

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 problems here: recursive dependency injection in your constructors and recursive mapping. To solve recursive DI - there are several options. First is to pass object factory instead of object itself to the constructor. Autofac supports that natively:

```
private readonly Func<IPatientMapper> patientMapper;
public CycleMapper(Func<IPatientMapper> patientMapper)
{
    this.patientMapper = patientMapper;
}
```

That way you delay construction of dependency until required, which resolves the issue.

Alternative approach - use property injection instead of constructor injection:

```
public IPatientMapper PatientMapper { get; set; }
```

And register like this (all your mappers):

```
builder.RegisterType<CycleMapper>().As<ICycleMapper>().SingleInstance().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
```

Now when first problem is solved - you will have stack overflow exception if you try to map your patient with cycles (because cycle has back reference to patient). Easiest way to solve this is to track what has already been mapped, like this (again, for all mappers, not just one):

```
public interface IPatientMapper {
    PatientViewModel GetViewModel(Patient patient, IDictionary<object, object> map = null);
}

public interface ICycleMapper {
    CycleViewModel GetViewModel(Cycle cycle, IDictionary<object, object> map = null);
}

public class CycleMapper : ICycleMapper
{
    public IPatientMapper PatientMapper { get; set; }

    public CycleViewModel GetViewModel(Cycle cycle, IDictionary<object, object> map = null)
    {
        if (cycle == null) {
            return null;
        }
        // If called without map - create new one
        if (map == null)
            map = new Dictionary<object, object>();
        // if we already mapped this cycle before - don't do this again
        // and instead return already mapped entity
        if (map.ContainsKey(cycle))
            return (CycleViewModel)map[cycle];

        var viewModel = new CycleViewModel();
        viewModel.PatientId = cycle.PatientId;
        viewModel.CycleId = cycle.CycleId;
        viewModel.IsActive = cycle.IsActive;
        // add this entity to map before calling any other mappers
        map.Add(cycle, viewModel);
        // pass map to other mapper
        viewModel.Patient = PatientMapper.GetViewModel(cycle.Patient, map);
        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

And when you need to map something, you just call

```
var model = mapper.GetViewModel(patient);
```

As usual and not care about circular dependencies any more.